# Verification: "$C \neq \emptyset$ is closed. Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Show $\text{d}(y,C)=0$ iff $y\in C$."

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Hope everything is going smoothly for everyone. I am hoping that someone can verify and critique my proof's accuracy, coherence, and general flow. Any criticism is welcome; I am trying to learn.

I state the problem in the attempt.
Also, note that $\text{d}(y,C) = \underset{x\in C}{\text{inf}}|x-y|$

**Results Employed**

Proposition 1 (from Abbott): Assume $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a lower bound for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then $\text{inf }A $ exists with $ \alpha = \text{inf }A $ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $a < \alpha + \epsilon$ for some $a \in A$.

**My Attempt**

Let $\emptyset \neq C$ be a closed set and $y\in \mathbb{R}$.  We want to show that $\text{d}(y, C) =0$ if and only if $y\in C$.

$\text{  }$ ($\Longleftarrow$)  Assume that $y \in C$. If this is the case, then for all $x \in C$ we have $0 < |x-y|$ when $x \neq y$ and $0 = |x-y|$ when $x = y$. Since $0 \leq |x-y|$ for all $x \in C$, $0$ is a lower bound for the set $\{|x-y|:x\in C\}$. Notice that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we have $0 + \epsilon > 0 = |y-y| \in \{|x-y|:x\in C\}$. This implies that $\text{d}(y,C) =0$ by Proposition 1.

$\text{  }$ ($\Longrightarrow$) Assume that $\text{d}(y,C) = 0$. Given this assumption, we know from Proposition 1 that $\exists a \in \{|x-y|:x\in C\}$ such that $0 + \epsilon > a$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$. This implies that $0 + \epsilon > a > 0 - \epsilon$, which means that $a \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(0)$. Here there are two cases, either $a = 0$ or $a \neq 0$. If $a = 0$, then $0 \in \{|x-y|:x\in C\}$, which means that for some $x \in C$, $|x-y|=0$. This implies $x = y$ and we get $y \in C$, as desired. For the other case where $a \neq 0$, we have that since $0 \neq a \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(0) \cap \{|x-y|:x\in C\}$, 0 is a limit point of $\{|x-y|:x\in C\}$. Since $\{|x-y|:x\in C\}$ is closed, we know that it contains all of its limit points, so $0 \in \{|x-y|:x\in C\}$. This means that there is some $x \in C$ such that $|x-y|=0$, implying that $x = y$ and hence $y \in C$.

$\text{  }$ Thus, we have that $\text{d}(y,C) =0$ if and only if $y\in C$.

Comment: What is the *Proposition 1.1*?

Comment: My apologies! I forgot to include this. I will include it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(\Longleftarrow)$ you can make the phrasing more clear but the idea is correct. The definition of $d(y, E)$ is $\inf\{|x - y| : x \in E\}$. Each $|x - y| \geq 0$ so the infimum $d(y, E) \geq 0$. Furthermore, $0 = |y - y| \in \{|x - y| : x \in E\}$ because $y \in E$. As $d(y, E)$ is a lower bound of that set (being the infimum), we must have $0 \geq d(y, E)$. Hence, $0 \leq d(y, E) \leq 0$ so $d(y, E) = 0$.

For $(\Longrightarrow)$ you have the basic idea but your solution is ultimately incorrect. The major issue is that you've swapped your quantifiers. You write that $d(y, E) = 0$ implies the existence of some $x \in E$ such that $a = |x - y| < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. But if $0 \leq a < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ then $a = 0$, thereby showing that $y \in E$ without using closedness of $E$! This is wrong because you swapped the $\exists a$ and $\forall \varepsilon$. The correct statement would be that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $a_\varepsilon = |x_\varepsilon - y|$ such that $a_\varepsilon < \varepsilon$. Notice that I gave a subscript to $a_\varepsilon$ and $x_\varepsilon$, as their existence is contingent on which $\varepsilon$ I take. The second issue is that you said $\{|x - y| : x \in E\}$ is closed without proof. You know that $E$ is closed, but why does that imply that this set is as well?

Here's how I would prove this direction. I'd start in the same way: let $\varepsilon > 0$ and use the assumption that $d(y, E) = 0$ to find some $x_\varepsilon \in E$ such that $|x_\varepsilon - y| < \varepsilon$. Thus, $x_\varepsilon \in B_\varepsilon(y) \cap E$, so for all $\varepsilon > 0$, the set $B_\varepsilon(y) \cap E$ is nonempty. Thus, $y \in \overline{E}$, which equals $E$ as we're assuming $E$ is closed. Thus, $y \in E$. In case you're not familiar with the $\overline E$ notation, it denotes the closure, i.e. $E$ with its limit points.

Comment: This is quite thorough and what I was hoping an answer for this would look like. I am grateful that you took the time to respond and further my learning. I have upvoted your answer but will wait with the check mark to motivate others to comment.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Let me know if you have any further questions regarding this answer.

Comment: Only upvote my answers if you come across them and feel they deserve an upvote! Feel free to delete it with no obligation. I'd imagine gaming the rep system like this is somehow against the site rules anyhow. In any case, do as you please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to delete my answer and I don't really wanna do a "rep trade" thing.